# Wordpress: how to include user ID inside the $wpdb to filter out results?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

So I have been struggling with this for a while now.

Right now I have this working code, which sums the total amount of meta_value.

```
<?php 
            
global $wpdb;
$meta_key = '_heart_this';
$all_downloads = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
SELECT sum(meta_value) 
FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = %s", $meta_key));

echo $all_downloads;
?>
```

The only thing that's left is to specify Wordpress user ID somewhere in that code, to filter the results for specific users.

Is that even possible?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The postmeta table doesn't have a field that stores user ID data so you'd need to find some other way to pull this data. How are you keeping track of who "hearted" what?

Comment: Yeah I figured. I'm trying to sum how much meta_value specific authors has. `meta_key` _heart_this is near the Wordpress `post_id` column. So wordpress knows how much meta_key value each post has. And Wordpress knows the author by post_id.

Comment: Well, you could fetch the IDs of the posts written by the author first and then run your query using said IDs to get only the results you want (eg. `AND post_id IN(...)`).